# Do you know any libraries that take an object and return a String representing how that object can be built using its builder class?

Tags: java, json, builder

Let's say I have the following POJO:

```
public class Student {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Student(){};

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

and its builder:

```
public class StudentBuilder {

    private Student student;

    public StudentBuilder() {
        this.student = new Student();
    }

    public StudentBuilder withFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.student.setFirstName(firstName);
        return this;
    }

    public StudentBuilder withLastName(String lastName) {
        this.student.setLastName(lastName);
        return this;
    }

    public Student build() {
        return this.student;
    }
}
```

Given that I have an instance of the Student class, is there a library that can take the student object as parameter and return a String representing the sentence to instantiate that specific object using its builder?

Usage should be something like:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student student = new Student("John", "Smith");     
        String builderInstantiator = StringObjectInstantiator.generate(student);
        Assert.assertEquals("new StudentBuilder().withFirstName(\"John\").withLastName(\"Smith\").build();", builderInstantiator);
}
```

I am thinking to ask around a bit before starting implementing it from scratch.

Short story:
One of the modules of the app I am working on will provision me with a json file containing serialized pojos.
Based on that json, I have to generate some java classes that instantiate those objects using their builders.

Input sample:

```
[
   {
       "firstName": "John",
       "lastName": "Smith"
   },
   {
       "firstName": "David",
       "lastName": "Winter"
   },
   {
       "firstName": "Rebecca",
       "lastName": "Cross"
   }
]
```

Output sample:

```
public class StudentProvider {

    public List<Student> get() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                new StudentBuilder().withFirstName("John").withLastName("Smith").build(),
                new StudentBuilder().withFirstName("David").withLastName("Winter").build(),
                new StudentBuilder().withFirstName("Rebecca").withLastName("Cross").build()
                );
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could find something in the code that implements IDE templates.

Comment: https://github.com/mkarneim/pojobuilder

Comment: Now you have made me very curios to why you are asking this :)

Comment: I've just edited the questions with a short version of my use case.

Comment: Do you have to use that builder class? Could you bypass using it entirely?  I would suggest using Google's [GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Using-Gson)

Comment: Yes, I have to use builder classess. The java class I have to generate should be decoupled from the json I receive as input.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you might be looking for some sort of code generation, but I don't think there would be library that does exactly what you want. You could try some builder generators like [pojo builder](https://github.com/mkarneim/pojobuilder) and edit the sources (or for eclipse plugins like [Fluent builders](https://code.google.com/p/fluent-builders-generator-eclipse-plugin/)).

In addition to that generating a string will be easy if the object contains only simple types like String, char, int etc. What code should it generate if you have a custom object in it. Say for instance if the Student class has a field of type Object what should be the value that need to be passed to withXXX() method? If you could guarantee the object under question will contain only simple fields the it would be better to write up your own method. Simply something like

```
public static String generate(Object obj){
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("new " + obj.getClass().getSimpleName() + "()");
    Field[] allFields = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : allFields) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
            str.append(".with").append(capitalize(field.getName())).append("(").append(resolveField(field.get(obj))).append(")");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        }
    return str.append(".build();").toString();
}
```

NB: This is a quick solution, may not be an ideal one. A complete example

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

class CustomObject {
    String innerValue1;
    String innerValue2;

    public CustomObject(String innerValue1, String innerValue2) {
        this.innerValue1 = innerValue1;
        this.innerValue2 = innerValue2;
    }
    public String getInnerValue1() {
        return innerValue1;
    }
    public void setInnerValue1(String innerValue1) {
        this.innerValue1 = innerValue1;
    }
    public String getInnerValue2() {
        return innerValue2;
    }
    public void setInnerValue2(String innerValue2) {
        this.innerValue2 = innerValue2;
    }
}

class Student {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int sample;
    private char sampleChar;
    private CustomObject obj;

    public Student(){};

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, int sample, char sampleChar, CustomObject obj) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.sample = sample;
    this.sampleChar = sampleChar;
    this.obj = obj;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getSample() {
        return sample;
    }

    public void setSample(int sample) {
        this.sample = sample;
    }

    public CustomObject getObj() {
        return obj;
    }

    public void setObj(CustomObject obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public char getSampleChar() {
        return sampleChar;
    }

    public void setSampleChar(char sampleChar) {
        this.sampleChar = sampleChar;
    }
}

public class StringObjectInstantiator {

    public static String generate(Object obj, boolean appenColon){
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("new " + obj.getClass().getSimpleName() + "()");
        Field[] allFields = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : allFields) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        try {
                str.append(".with").append(capitalize(field.getName())).append("(").append(resolveField(field.get(obj))).append(")");
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
        str.append(".build()");
        return appenColon ?  str.append(";").toString() : str.toString();
    }

    private static String resolveField(Object fieldValue) {
        String className = fieldValue.getClass().getSimpleName();
        if("String".equals(className)){
            return "\"" + fieldValue + "\"";
        } else if("Character".equals(className)){
            return "'" + fieldValue + "'";
        } else if("Number".equals(fieldValue.getClass().getSuperclass().getSimpleName())){
            return fieldValue.toString();
        } else {
            return generate(fieldValue, false);
        }
    }

    private static String capitalize(final String line) {
       return Character.toUpperCase(line.charAt(0)) + line.substring(1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(generate(new Student("James", "Bond", 2, 'J', new CustomObject("A", "B")), true));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the sample! Since I don't think someone wrote a library for my use case, I will follow this approach of using reflection + recursion. I actually wrote most of it, just that I wanted to check if there is a more elegant way of doing it. :-). The POJOs I am working on are not containing only primitive members. I wish! :-) They also contain Lists, Maps, other objects etc, so I will spend some time handling all of them. Anyway, thanks for the sample!